# Why is it important to study the eigenvalues of the Laplacian?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, harmonic-functions

Why is it important to study the eigenvalues of the Laplacian acting on regions in $\mathbb R^n$? What information does this give us? What problems does this information help us solve?

In particular, if $0$ is in the spectrum, does this tell us anything about the solvability of the Dirichlet or Poisson problem for the region? This second question is motivated by the following theorem that I found while flipping through Davies' *Spectral Theory and Differential Operators*. From the emphasis he puts on it and the amount of work he did to prove it, I feel it must be important, but I can't say why.

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ be regular, and let $H$ be the
>   Friedrichs extension of $\small -\triangle$ initially defined on
>   $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Then $0\in \operatorname{Spec} H$ if and only if
>   the inradius of $\Omega$ is infinite.

Comment: Are you asking what the spectrum of Laplacian on $\Omega$ tells us about $\Omega$ itself ?

Comment: @nonlinearism Not really. I know that's a big, famous problem. I'm looking for more basic things, especially relating to the Dirichlet and Poisson PDEs.

Comment: $+1$ I've been wondering this for a long while. The eigenvalues of the Laplacian are apparently important in Riemannian geometry, but like you, I have no idea why.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454922/simplicity-and-isolation-of-the-first-eigenvalue-associated-with-some-differenti

Answer (score 17):

The spectrum of $-\Delta$ reveals properties of light, heat, sound, and atomic phenomena. I'll briefly summarize.

The **heat equation**
$$
           \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = c\Delta u,
$$
can be solved if you have a complete basis of eigenfunctions for $\Delta u$. The eigenvalues give the time decay rates of the eigenfunctions in time. More explicitly, if $(-\Delta) e_{\lambda} = \lambda e_{\lambda}$, then
$$
          u(x,t)=e^{-c\lambda t}e_{\lambda}(x)
$$
is a solution of the heat equation, and, in principle, a full solution can be built from linear (discrete or continuous) sums of such solutions. This comes from the classical problem of separation of variables originally proposed by Fourier in his *Treatise on Heat Conduction*. Spectral Theory has its origins here.

In a similar way, one may develop solutions of the **wave equation**:
$$
            \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}=\frac{1}{c^{2}}\Delta u.
$$
The wave equation governs the time-dependent behavior of the electric field in a homogenous, isotropic, source-free material. (The propogation of light is described through the wave equation.) In this case the eigenvalues determine the modulation frequency for a particular eigenfunction through separation of variables. This corresponds to classical notions of prism and spectrum. For a string fixed at two endpoints and undergoing small vibrations, the classical one-dimensional wave equation describes mechanical displacements, and gives a fundamental vibrational mode and all integer multiples of those modes (a.k.a. harmonics.) This relates to sound, and it's almost certain that this is the origin of the term "harmonic anaysis." The harmonic frequencies are derived from the eigenvalues of $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$. A circular drum head is similarly analyzed from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 2-d Laplacian. The resonant frequencies of the drum are non-harmonic and are derived from the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

The non-relativistic hydrogen atom has a corresponding Quantum Mechanical **Schrodinger Wave equation**
$$
   i\hbar\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\Delta \psi + \frac{e^{2}}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}r}\psi .
$$
Though the problem is not fully reduced to eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\Delta$, the eigenvalues of $\Delta$ on functions defined on the unit spherical shell (spherical harmonics) have to do with the permissible values of the orbital energies of the atom; this reveals much about the orbital shells, and the spectral lines of the Hydrogen atom. Remember S, P, D, F from Chemistry? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital.

There are applications to fluids as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you say why it is important to know if $0$ is in the spectrum of the Laplacian or not? Does it have anything to do with the solvability of the Dirichlet or Poisson problem on a region?

Comment: I suppose that if we know it isn't, we can always invert it and solve the equation. At least, this seems to get a "weak" solution. Right?

Comment: @Potato: $(-\Delta f,f) \ge 0$ for $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$. The Friedrichs extension of $-\Delta$ is guaranteed to have the same lower bound as the original operator: i.e., if $(-\Delta f,f) \ge \epsilon(f,f)$ for some $\epsilon$ and all $f$, this bound is preserved by the Friedrichs extension. $\epsilon=0$ on free space. Preserving this bound was the original goal of the Friedrichs extension and answered an open question of this type at the time. That's why they mention that bound. Yes, it has to do with the invertibility of $\Delta_{f}$ and the continuity of the inverse.

Comment: Could you explain the invertibility issue a little more? For example, if I want to solve $\small \Delta f=0$ in a disk, it seems like naively inverting just gives $f=\Delta^{-1}0=0$. So the boundary conditions have to come into play somehow.

Comment: To completely define the eigenvalue problem or to find the solution of Laplace PDE, you have define the domain in which the solutions lie. For example, you need to specify the boundary value of Dirichlet solution, and boundary flux for Neumann. The solution and the spectrum is different for Dirichlet problem, compared to Neumann problem. Also required are the smoothness properties of the desired solutions.

Comment: @Potato: For the disk, the Friedrichs extension has a domain which is obtained by first closing $C^{\infty}_{c}(D)$ under the norm $\|f\|_{1}=\sqrt{(-\Delta f,f)+(f,f)}$. Then one selects out the functions in this space which are in the domain of the adjoint $(-\Delta)^{\star}$ of the original $-\Delta$. That defines the Friedrichs extension. This particular selfadjoint extension of the original operator is continuously invertible on the disk $D$. So, the only solution of Laplace's equation in the domain of $\Delta_{f}$ is $0$.

Comment: @T.A.E. I see. So knowing $\Delta_f$ is invertible doesn't really help you solve the Dirichlet problem, since you can't take into account boundary values, right?

Comment: @T.A.E. Oh, I think I have this figured out now. Some Googling tells me that different boundary conditions on a region give different Friedrich's extensions. Then everything works out. Is this the case?

Comment: @Potato: For the disk $D$: when you close the space of compactly supported functions under the $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ norm I mentioned above, essentially your functions vanish on the boundary of the disk. So the Friedrichs extension of the original $\Delta$ with domain $C^{\infty}_{c}(D)$ ends up having a domain $\mathcal{D}(\Delta_{f})$ where the functions vanish at the boundary of $D$. There are sticky details for general regions, but that's the idea. So solutions of Laplace's equation in the domain of $\Delta_{f}$ must "vanish at the boundary" and, hence, are 0. That's how things are well-posed.

Comment: @T.A.E. Is there a way to adapt the extension procedure to for nontrivial boundary values? (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: @Potato: Only if the operator remains semi-bounded. Von Neumann originally had found a way to extend semibounded symmetric operators to selfadjoint, but maybe with a slightly worse lower bound, but which could be arbitrarily close. It was Friedrichs who showed that there was a construction that would extend to a selfadjoint operator with the *same* lower bound. There are probably many others, but Friedrichs' extension was such a nice construction that it became standard, and important to the general theory of unbounded, semibounded symmetric operators with selfadjoint extensions.